# Detect test failures on jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, junit, tdd

I have been playing around Jenkins since 5 days but I have a problem. I have a Java Code that has been unit tested with JUnit and I am using Gradle Build to build the code. I have deliberately tried to fail a test out of the three tests and gradle build reports a failure! which was expected. Yet I pushed my code onto github [SampleTestProject](https://github.com/exorcist007/SampleTestProject.git) and a build was triggered on Jenkins after a minute(as configured). Yet jenkins marks the build as successful even though the test was failed while building on a local machine!!

The Code that I am going to post is really bad yet it is ok to have a hands-on experience on jenkins

The Main class

```
   package com.bitwise.test;

    /**
     * Created by AniruddhaS on 2/11/2016.
     */
    public class Hello {
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello";
        }

        public int addArgs(int i, int i1) {
            return (i+i1);
        }

        public String sayBye() {
            return "Bye";
        }

        public int mulArgs(int i, int i1) {
            return (i*i1);
        }
    }
```

The Test class

```
package com.bitwise.test;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.suppliers.TestedOn;

/**
 * Created by AniruddhaS on 2/11/2016.
 */
public class HelloTest {
    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnHelloOnCallingHelloMethod(){
        //given
        Hello vector=new Hello();
        //when
        Assert.assertSame("Hello",vector.sayHello());
        //then
    }
    @Test
    public void itShouldReturnAValueAfterAdditionOfTheArgumentValues(){
        //given
        Hello adder=new Hello();
        //when
        Assert.assertEquals(3,adder.addArgs(2,1));
        //then
    }
    @Test
    public void itShouldPrintByeWhenRelevantFunctionIsCalled(){
        //given
        Hello bye=new Hello();
        //when
        Assert.assertSame("Bye",bye.sayBye());
        //then
    }
    @Test
    public void itShouldMultiply(){
        //given
        Hello bye=new Hello();
        //when


       Assert.assertEquals(6,bye.mulArgs(5,3));/*here mulArgs emits 15 but 
                                     test fails since expected value is 6*/
        //then
    }
}
```

build.gradle

```
group 'hello'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
task test1<<
        {
    println("hello, test running")
}

test{
    testLogging{
        events 'started','passed'
        events 'started','failed'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

---

Kindly suggest how to sort out the above problem!

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Does the build output show that the test fails (which Jenkins doesn't then notice) or is the actual problem that the test is passing when your build is run through Jenkins?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you running the Gradle script?

Whether you're using an "Execute shell" step to do something like `./gradlew test`, or you're using the [Gradle plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) to execute your `test` task, Jenkins *will* mark the build as **failed** if the Gradle script fails, e.g. due to a test assertion failure.

But what you want is for the Jenkins build to be marked as *unstable* rather than *failed*.

To do so, you need to update your Gradle script to not treat test failures as fatal in your `test` block of the `build.gradle`:

```
test {
  ignoreFailures = true
}
```

Then you can run your Gradle script in Jenkins and let it [analyse](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) the JUnit results, which will set the build status to *successful* or *unstable*, depending on whether the tests pass or fail.

The Gradle `java` plugin writes test results in JUnit XML format to `build/test-results/TEST-HelloTest.xml` (in your example).

To analyse the results, go to "Post-build actions" in the job configuration, and add "Publish JUnit test result report", and enter `**/TEST-*.xml` in the "Test report XMLs" field.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't understand your code but you can add post-build actions in jenkins which can affect the status of the job.

eg : [Text finder plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin) : 
search keywords in the log files you specified and use that to downgrade a "successful" build to be a failure.

[Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin) : to show summary of errors and warnings

Comment: In the test class code I made an error deliberately marked by the comment. While running the tests locally, I get an Assertion Error but jenkins doesn't' do that and it Passes the test.

Comment: Post build actions will help you only to mark test  as failure if it finds "Assertion Error" in the build log (if you configure it to search text Assertion Error).

But if you get error locally and not in jenkins job then you need to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Jenkins has a JUnit plugin (which you probably already have installed), so it's a much better idea to use that to parse the test results, rather than relying on text in the console output.